# Can't add view to custom RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-relativelayout

I'm very new to the world of Android Programming (originally iOS developer), and I'm a bit confused about adding views programatically. I've got a custom Relative Layout that is showing up well in my Activity, and I have to add views into it dynamically. That's where I'm stuck ... So here is my custom view :

```
public class BoardView extends RelativeLayout {

    // Initialisation
    @Override public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        int size = width > height ? height : width;
        setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
        this.addView(new Button(this.getContext()));
    }

    // Required constructors
    public BoardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public BoardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public BoardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
}
```

Then in my activity I'm trying to do this :

```
public class MainGameView extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_activity);


        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.view);
        Button bouton = new Button(this);
        bouton.setText("ok");
        bouton.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT,WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        params.leftMargin = 107;
        layout.addView(bouton, params);
    }
}
```

Seems very simple to me, but cannot get this to work ... The BoardView remains empty. Can anybody explain me how I'm supposed to do this ? Thank you in advance.

If you need the xml to help me, here it is :
(BoardView at the very bottom)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/barre_menu"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:text="SCORE"
            android:id="@+id/textViewScore"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SCORE"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textViewScore"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewScore"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewScore"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/picto_menu" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:background="@drawable/picto_restart"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewScore"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewScore" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout">

        <fr.wiboyd.arnaud.kilo.Views.TileButton
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView">

        <fr.wiboyd.arnaud.kilo.Views.BoardView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#cccccc" />

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT :** 
Screenshot of the app. The grey square is the BoardView. I expect a button to be drawn in it, but it doesn't ...
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW15A.png)

Comment: are you sure it is not only hidden by another element? Your RelativeLayout is just 100dp high and there are so much other objects inside. Could you show a screenshot how it is and how it should be?

Comment: The 100dp high Relative View is another one, the one I'm talking about is the "BoardView" at the bottom of the xml file. I'll edit my post with a screenshot.
edit : can't put a picture because i'm new here. So link leads to the screenshot ;)

Comment: I'm assuming that's a debugging trial, but don't add `View`s in the `onMeasure()` method. That is, remove the `this.addView(...);` line there. Also, if you don't call the `super` method in `onMeasure()`, you need to handle measuring out each child `View` yourself, by calling its `measure()` method appropriately. Otherwise, the child `View`s will end up with 0 width and height.

Comment: Debugging trial indeed. Edited my code, and adding super.onMeasure solved the problem. Don't know why I forgot it, thank you very much !